# Disable magnifying glass from GoogleMap on android

Tags: android, google-maps

Im creating an application in Android and I show a location using latitude and longitude on GoogleMaps from Android.

I have implemented the maps following the next code: https://gist.github.com/joshdholtz/4522551

When I implement this in my code I get the screen of my phone as shown: [image]

I dont know exactly what is that magnifying glass at the left of my map. I want to remove that.

I have disable most of the UIsetting from the map.

```
map = googleMap;
    map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setIndoorLevelPickerEnabled(false);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
```

And when I click on the magnifying glass im getting an exception:

```
    Process: com.itcom202.weroom, PID: 29587
java.lang.NullPointerException: Place Fields must be set.
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:889)
    at com.google.android.libraries.places.internal.dt.onClick(Unknown Source:4)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Can someone tell me what exactly is that and how to disable it? I want to allow the user only scroll and zoom from GoogleMap